# git rebase and keep all child branches

Tags: git

I'm trying to import a CVS repository into git.  Unfortunately, we've been using a really old method of creating releases from our CVS repo, that doesn't involve any actual CVS branches or tags, but keep that information in a separate system.  Consequently, almost all of the development happens on the CVS trunk.  So, one file may be added very early in the history, but doesn't become part of the release for 6 months.

What I'd like to do is import this CVS repo into git, and use rebasing to move these commits to development branches.  I do have some branches from CVS though, so I really want to move all branches.

Say I've got this:

```
                  F---G---H topic
                 /
A---B---C---D---E---I---J master
```

`B` is the commit that I want to move to its own branch.  I want the result to look like this:

```
                F`---G`---H` topic
               /
A---C`---D`---E`---I`---J` master
 \
  B some_unfinished_feature
```

But rebasing only `master` results in:

```
git checkout -b some_unfinished_feature B
git rebase --onto A B master

A---C`---D`---E`---I`---J` master
 \
  \               F---G---H topic
   \             /
    B---C---D---E
     \-some_unfinished_feature
```

Can I get git to rebase `topic` onto `E'` in one rebase command?  I could potentially have lots of branches that I want to move onto their corresponding new commit.  Or is there a way that I can get a mapping between `E` and `E'`?

Comment: Do you want to iterate chronologically through the whole trunk, manually choosing which topic branch (if any) the current commit should be "syphoned" off into, or do you want only look for commits to move into branches.  IOW, how common are the commits to move?  If common, a `filter-branch` might make sense, otherwise it's probably better to automate the syphoning process.  I wrote a utility called [`ggrbm`](https://github.com/aspiers/git-config/blob/master/bin/ggrbm) ("Git Rebase Multiple") which could help with this, but might need further development first.

Answer (score 2):

```
               F---G---H topic
              /
 A---B---C---D---E---I---J master

 git checkout B
 git branch BRANCH-B
 git checkout master
 git rebase -i  HEAD~6
```

(remove commit B)

```
 git rebase --onto D' D topic
```

This should do it assuming no conflict ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your question you want to move starting from `C` commit. `B` is left as branch based on `A`.

First we should give name to it:

```
git branch -b some_unfinished_feature <B-ish>
```

This command will create `some_unfinished_feature` branch starting from `<B-ish>` commit.

The `<C-ish>` is upstream. You can view all commits that would be rebased:

```
git log <C-ish>..topic
```

You can notice that `I` and `J` will not be rebased because those are different branch. You should rebase it separately later.

Now rebase your `topic` onto `<A-ish>` starting from `<C-ish>`:

```
git rebase -p --onto <A-ish> <C-ish> topic
```

`-p` flag will preserve any merges which occur from `<C-ish>` to `topic`

When this command complete you will get:

```
       some_unfinished_feature
     /
A---B---C---D---E---I---J master
  \
   C`---D`---E`
              \   
                F`---G`---H` topic
```

Now you should rebase `master` onto `<E-ish>`  from `<I-ish>`

```
git rebase -p --onto <E-ish> <I-ish> master
```

Voila:

```
A---B some_unfinished_feature
  \
   C`---D`---E`--I`---J` master
              \   
                F`---G`---H` topic
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to move `topic` would be:

```
git rebase --onto E' E topic
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this automatically for a bunch of different branches, and that is by design.  Each rebase potentially introduces conflicts that must be resolved manually.

Alternately, you might be able to use [git filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) with your configuration management software to script the changes you want, but that's potentially a lot of work.  It might make more sense to keep `master` as your development branch, and use `filter-branch` to make a release branch, rather than the other way around.

Comment: How do I know what `E'` is though?  After the rebase is done, there's no connection between `E` and `E'`.  How do I get git to tell me the mapping between the old commit sha1s and the rebased ones?

Comment: Match up the log messages, I suppose.  You can make an `old-master` before rebasing `master` so you can see both at the same time.

Comment: That seems fragile, at best.  It's entirely possible to have 2 commits with the same log message.  I guess I could use `git rev-list` to get a list of revisions on `old-master` and `master`, because the number of commits and the order of commits should be the same... but that's a lot of work.

Comment: To build a map from E to E', use git filter-branch, and make the commit-filter record the old and new SHA1.  (It's not going to be pretty no matter how you do it....)

Answer (score 0):

First, a word of advice : when reabasing, work with a temporary branch :

```
git branch wip_topic
git checkout wip_topic
```

Once you have a successful rebase (and checked that it works...), you can move your original head to the working commit :

```
git checkout topic
git reset --hard wip_topic
git branch -d wip_topic
```

(if you didn't and something bad happens, `git reflog` can still save your bacon ...)

---

When doing a rebase, git skips commits where the commit's textual diff matches an existing commit on the target branch.

If your `master` rebase did not introduce too many conflicts, applying :

```
git rebase --onto A B wip_topic
```

should give you the desired result.

Generally, most conflicts will appear near the "beginning" of the rebased commit list (<-- pinch of salt).
Say you had conflicts when building commit `C'`, but none afterwards, you can rebase the `C..topic` part :

```
git rebase --onto C' C wip_topic
```

Anyhow : try it, and see what `git`'s black magic does.